# Анонсы записи wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте нету кнопки "Читать далее" посмотрел в index.php там вроде как прописано.

```css
<div class="entry">
<?php the_content("Продолжить чтение " . the_title('', '', false)); ?>
</div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<div>Читать статью полностью</div></a>
```

В Archive.php стоит

```
    <div class="entry"> <?php the_excerpt () ?>
```

Как вывести на сайт кнопку читать далее. 
Помог плагин Advanced Excerpt но выводит все ужасно. 
Может чем поможете?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то вот то что вам нужно. 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/58a36246440447348d587e5cec575750.png

Comment: К большому сожалению нет(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_excerpt ()` выводит цитату поста (первые n символов, либо текст из отдельно заполняемого поля "цитата") без ссылки на саму статью.

Попробуйте заменить

```
<div class="entry"> <?php the_excerpt (); ?></div>
```

на

```
<div class="entry"> <?php the_content("Продолжить чтение " . the_title('', '', false)); ?></div>
```

Либо выведите ссылку на статью отдельно:

```
<div class="entry"> <?php the_excerpt (); ?></div>
<div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more">Читать далее</a></div>
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Помог второй вариант

Comment: Такой вот вопрос. Сейчас на сайте отображается кнопка читать подробнее. Но визуально не очень красиво. Может подскажете как визуально в виде кнопки сделать? или по правому краю выровнять.

Comment: Всё оформление можно выполнить средствами css. Задаёте классу кнопки высоту, ширину, скругляете углы, меняете цвет текста и т. д.